# IE8 only displaying background image when mouse hover out of <body>

Tags: javascript, html, css, internet-explorer-8

I'm having a strange bug on IE8. I have a background image on a `::after` pseudo element of a specific div, which changes when the dropdown is open/closed. The problem is: Only on IE8, when i open the dropdown, the image doesn't change until i hover my mouse out of the page area. Then, the image is displayed.

Some images to illustrate the situation:

[image]

Opened the dropdown...

[image]

Then the image finally appears
[image]

**My HTML Code**:

```
<ul class="nav navbar-nav">
<div class="ul-title duvidas" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#ajuda-collapse-1" aria-expanded="false">
    <div class="ul-collapse" id="topic-maquininhas">Test
         <!-- ::after goes here -->
    </div>
</div>
<div class="collapse subtopic-container" id="ajuda-collapse-1">
    <li id="subtopic-maquininhas-mensagens">
        Subtest1
    </li>
    <li id="subtopic-maquininhas-utilizacao">
        Subtest2
    </li>
    <li id="subtopic-maquininhas-servicos">
        Subtest3
    </li>
    <li id="subtopic-maquininhas-suporte">
        Subtest4
    </li>
</div>
</ul>
```

**:after CSS (expanded)**

```
ul.active .ul-title.duvidas > .ul-collapse:after {
content: "";
float: right;
width: 16px;
height: 10px;
margin-top: 6px;
background: url(../images/sprites.png) no-repeat -118px -34px;
}
```

**:after CSS (collapsed)**

```
.ul-title.duvidas > .ul-collapse:after {
content: "";
float: right;
width: 16px;
height: 10px;
margin-top: 6px;
background: url(../images/sprites.png) no-repeat -70px -34px;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe this is your Problem:

> In Windows Internet Explorer 8, as well as later versions of Windows Internet Explorer in IE8 Standards mode, only the one-colon form of this pseudo-element is recognized—that is, :after.

Source: https://msdn.microsoft.com/de-de/library/cc304076(v=vs.85).aspx

EDIT: It seems that this is a IE8 Bug, where pseudo :after elements are displayed behind the Image you put it on. Try raising the z-index of your :after element

Comment: Do you really need the :after element? I mean, since you are not adding any content to them, you could just use another class or ID

Comment: And about the background image? `.ul-title.duvidas > .ul-collapse:after {
(...)
background: url(../images/sprites.png) no-repeat -70px -34px;
}` Isn't it attached to the :after element? I guess that if I put it on another place, it will break the layout...

Comment: Don't make a guess, just try it ;)